# Reading data in a listview without a selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a timer running on an Update Panel with a Listview showing a page size of 1. The timer increments the data pager as it cycles through many records.

In the Protected Sub timer_Tick Event I would like to read a few values from the ListView Page. Is there an easy way to do this?

The data is currently binding via a SQLDataSource, but this is temporary while other page development is underway. So I cannot rely on that data set for getting the info needed.

Something like....

```
val1 = listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
val2 = listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
```

One issue is that the record will not be selected. The Listview is displaying the data set in an ItemTemplate.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
   <td>Position C:</td>
   <td><asp:Label ID="Label50" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval "Pos_C") %>' />
   </td>                        
</tr>                                        
<tr>
   <td>Position D</td>
   <td><asp:Label ID="Label51" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pos_D") %>' />
   </td>
</tr> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Abbreviated layout of itemtemplate.

Comment: Are you only interested in getting the items selected?

Comment: No the item is not selected, it is a single record per Data Pager and I only need two fields from the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved the above question with the code below....

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound

    'Get the item object.
    Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem = CType(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
    Dim item As ListViewItem = e.Item

    ' Get the Label control in the item.      
    Dim myVal1Lbl As Label = CType(item.FindControl("Label50"), Label)
    Dim myVal2Lbl As Label = CType(item.FindControl("Label51"), Label)

    Dim myVal1 As String = myVal1Lbl.Text
    Dim myVal2 As String = myVal2Lbl.Text

End Sub
```

Works great.